# iPhone X home indicator dimming/undimming

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uikit, iphone-x

I am dimming home indicator on iPhone X using this:

```
 override var preferredScreenEdgesDeferringSystemGestures: UIRectEdge {
    return [.bottom]
 }
```

Now in a child view controller (which is added using addChildViewController), I want to restore it back to normal state (i.e. always bright). I tried overriding this var in the child view controller to []

```
  override var preferredScreenEdgesDeferringSystemGestures: UIRectEdge {
    return []
}
```

and also,

```
 override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    self.setNeedsUpdateOfHomeIndicatorAutoHidden()
    self.setNeedsUpdateOfScreenEdgesDeferringSystemGestures()
}
```

But nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How do you use your added child view controller?

Comment: Well, using addChild and then adding it's view as subview.

Comment: What's the new API?

Comment: Hello @matt , can you please tell which new API you are referring to?

Comment: Try overriding prefersHomeIndicatorAutoHidden if you want to hide home indicator.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your overridden ***preferredScreenEdgesDeferringSystemGestures*** in child view controller ever gets called if you add your child view controller using ***addChild*** (i.e. not really presenting it). I'd suggest doing the following in your main view controller:

```swift
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    setNeedsUpdateOfScreenEdgesDeferringSystemGestures()    
}

override var preferredScreenEdgesDeferringSystemGestures: UIRectEdge {
    return children.contains { type(of: $0) == ChildViewController.self } ? [] : [.bottom]
}
```

Where ***ChildViewController*** is your child view controller class.

When you add your child view controller's view as subview of your main view controller ***viewDidLayoutSubviews*** will be called and ***setNeedsUpdateOfScreenEdgesDeferringSystemGestures*** will trigger your overridden ***preferredScreenEdgesDeferringSystemGestures*** where you check whether you have a child view controller of type ***ChildViewController*** and return required values accordingly.

**UPDATE:**

As @matt pointed out, overriding ***childForScreenEdgesDeferringSystemGestures*** will query child view controller for the same:

```swift
class ChildViewController: UIViewController {

    override var preferredScreenEdgesDeferringSystemGestures: UIRectEdge {
        return []
    }

    // showing home indicator for child view controller
    override var prefersHomeIndicatorAutoHidden: Bool {
        return false
     }

}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        setNeedsUpdateOfScreenEdgesDeferringSystemGestures()
    }

    override var preferredScreenEdgesDeferringSystemGestures: UIRectEdge {
        return [.bottom]
    }

    override var childForScreenEdgesDeferringSystemGestures: UIViewController? {
        return children.first { type(of: $0) == ChildViewController.self }
    }

    // hiding home indicator
    override var prefersHomeIndicatorAutoHidden: Bool {
        return true
    }

    // querying child view controller for home indicator preference 
    override var childForHomeIndicatorAutoHidden: UIViewController? {
        return children.first { type(of: $0) == ChildViewController.self }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is clever, but it ignores the fact that this mechanism is already built-in.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a child view controller's `preferredScreenEdgesDeferringSystemGestures` to be consulted, the parent view controller must implement `childForScreenEdgesDeferringSystemGestures` to point to that child.

Comment: Do you know of a way to disable pull down notifications if one slides down from the top left or right corners of the screen>